# MLE of $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\exp\left({-\frac{1}{2}(x-\theta)}^2\right)$

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, estimators

Consider a random sample of size $n$ from a distribution with probability density function (pdf) is given by

$$f(x;\theta)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
 \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-\theta)^2}&\text{if }\space x\geq \theta \\ 
 0&\text{elsewhere} 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Find the maximum likelihood estimator of $\theta$.

My attempt,

\begin{align}L(\theta)&=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}e^{-1/2(x_i-\theta)^2}\\&=\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\theta)^2\right)\cdot \textrm{constant}\end{align}

$$\therefore~\log L=-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\theta)^2+\textrm{constant}$$

\begin{align}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\log L&=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\theta)\\&=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i-n\theta\\\implies n\theta &=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i\\ \implies \hat{\theta}&=\bar{x}\end{align}

Am I correct?

Comment: Yes you found how to get the MLE for the mean of a Gaussian distributed sample.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings Given the constraint on the support, which leaves us with the right half of a unit variance Gaussian, I would imagine the MLE of $\theta$ is much smaller than $\bar{x}$

Comment: When the support depends on the parameter, instead of flatly differentiating (which isn't really justified here), pay attention to the parameter space given the sample.

Comment: @khol I had missed that part. It is indeed as Jarle stated. For the half normal distribution the likelihood function is zero unless $\theta$ is smaller than the smallest $x_i$. Thus you get a $\mathcal{L}(\theta)$ which is a parabolic function centered at $\bar{x}>x_{(1)}$, but cut off to 0 at the point $x_{(1)}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For $\theta\le x_{(1)}$ the likelihood is an increasing function of $\theta$ and for $\theta>x_{(1)}$, the likelihood is zero. Hence, the MLE of $\theta$ is $\hat\theta=X_{(1)}$.